# How to Post to a Discord Webhook with Discord.js (code 400 Bad Request)?

Tags: node.js, discord, webhooks, discord.js

I'm trying to access a discord Webhook using Nodejs for simple messages (for now).

I have looked at several attempts here and at other places, but didn't quite understand them or was able to replicate them myself. Reading through the [docs](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook) and searching online I found [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) which in my eyes should work fine in principle, while seemingly simpler.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
          var webhook = {
            "id":"my webhook id",
            "token":"my webhook token"
          };
          var URL = `https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/${webhook.id}/${webhook.token}`;

          fetch(URL, {
            "method":"POST",
            "payload": JSON.stringify({
              "content":"test"
            })
          })
            .then(res=> console.log(res));
```

The only output I ever get is a Response Object with status code 400. The only time I do get something else is when I remove the method, then I get code 200 which doesn't help much...
Is my payload somehow completely wrong or did I make a mistake with the URL or fetch syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of making your own POST request, you can use the [`WebhookClient`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient) built into Discord.js like so...

```js
const id = '';
const token = '';

const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient(id, token);

webhook.send('Hello world.')
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Worked on the first try. Thanks for showing this, a native solution like this is perfect!

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 small mistakes in your request resulting in the error 400 :

- there is no Content-Type in the header
- the `payload`attribute must be replaced by `body`

  ```
  var URL = `https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/${webhook.id}/${webhook.token}`;
  fetch(URL, {
       "method":"POST",
       "headers": {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
       "body": JSON.stringify({
          "content":"test"
        })

      })
      .then(res=> console.log(res))
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  ```

Comment: I get an error 'Unexpected string', you forgot a comma after your header object. But even with a comma i still get code 400

Comment: I succeeded with this code:
`axios.post(\`https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/${webhook.id}/${webhook.token}\`, { content: 'test' })`